# Use if, else in function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use nelow query for use if,but occur error

```
CREATE FUNCTION getStationCityCode
(
    @stationCode int
)
RETURNS bigint
AS BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
          if((select cityCode from Station where code=@stationCode)!=0)
        select cityCode from Station where code=@stationCode
          else
             select 1 as cityCode
    )
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `CASE` expression

```
CREATE FUNCTION getStationCityCode
(
    @stationCode int
)
RETURNS bigint
AS BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN cityCode!=0 THEN cityCode ELSE 1 END as cityCode
        FROM Station 
        WHERE code=@stationCode
    )
END
```